# nav-view="stage" field in Ionic does not get 'opacity: 1' on android

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

Im building an ionic app. when I run it on browser, the field [nav-view="stage"] gets 'opacity: 1' that override its initialized 'opacity:0'. But when I run it on an android device, I see white screen and the field [nav-view="stage"] does not get 'opacity 1' and stuck with 'opacity: 0'.
I can override it with !important in the css file, but I was wondering if there is a better practice solution? something that takes care of javascript that suppose to change this value?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

At this time (2015-01-18) it is a reported problem in ionic version 1.2 that is still unresolved:

See: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4556

There is an answer from a user to solve this problem. You have to manually patch ionic js src and add `css.opacity = 1;` for android transition